# Found 3pin usb cable name. But I don't know the name of this cable

Tags: usb, cable, camera, pin

I bought a camera module from AliExpress.
[image: picture of camera module from AliExpress]

I'm looking for a cable to connect to Nvidia Jetson.

[image: Picture of the module and Nvidia Jetson]
This is the module I used before.

[image: The cable used for connection]
This is using a 3-pin USB cable.

What I want is the cable needed for the module 3-pin in the first picture.
What do you call cables like this?

Comment: The image of the 3-pin USB cable has more than 3-pins based on the number of cables going to the header. I see 4-pins at least.

Comment: And I see 4 cables

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, it could be confusing.The second and third pictures are the camera modules and cables currently being used.

What I want is the cable needed for the module 3-pin in the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB mouse cable
USB extension cable
USB mouse replacement cable

Comment: Thanks to you, I found it on Google.I was able to find it with the "USB mouse cable" keyword.